# Which version to use for RoboGuice

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, roboguice

I'm starting a new project and would like to use Sherlock and RoboGuice, I saw there are some examples to combine both, but while browsing RoboGuice GitHub I realized the author actually added the combined classes, however the .jar the wiki advices to install is the 2.0 version.
But, there are already some 2.x versions, 3.x and even a 4.x versions compiled.

Which .jar should I use in order to have this new special classes without adding complexity to my project (adding another library).

Or is the only option cloning the git and using it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just received and answer in the official repo (if it's of some use for someone), and I quote:

> If you want to be bleeding edge, go ahead and use 3.0 but it's not
>   supported yet.  For a normal app I'd say use roboguice 2 with
>   Roberto's lib, which are the same files now included in rg3
>   https://github.com/rtyley/roboguice-sherlock